# Only inserting row when record doesn't already exist

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

The table is called `limits` and takes the following fields:

```
id    |    ip    |    limit
```

on every page load, I'm checking if the user has a record in this table (determined by `ip`) and if they don't, I insert a record. However if the record already exists, I don't want to do anything.

I basically need a `INSERT IF NOT EXISTS` type query. I've already read [this](http://bogdan.org.ua/2007/10/18/mysql-insert-if-not-exists-syntax.html) and the `INSERT IGNORE` example looks good but as far as I can tell it only works for primary keys. In my case the `id` field is the primary key and I want to check if the `ip` already exists.

Here's some sort of pseudo SQL code:

```
INSERT INTO `limits` (ip, limit)
VALUES ('127.0.0.1', 8)
IF NOT EXISTS `limits`.`ip`
```

Thanks for any help!

EDIT: tried this too

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `limits`
SET `ip` = ‘127.0.0.1′,
`limit` = 8;
```

Comment: `INSERT IGNORE` will work on a `UNIQUE` key as well.

Comment: Sweet. Can you give me an example on how to use it as an answer? That way I can accept it. I edited my attempt into the post.

Comment: Actually nevermind, when I copied from the website it got a weird character in there instead of `'`. It works :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`INSERT IGNORE` will ignore any unique indexes, whether it's the primary key or any unique key.

You can create a unique key on IP using

```
ALTER TABLE limits
  ADD CONSTRAINT idx_limits_ip
  UNIQUE (ip)
```

The [Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-table.html) has a few alternative syntax to create indexes.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO `limits` (ip, limit)
SELECT '127.0.0.1', 8
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `limits` WHERE `limits`.`ip` =  '127.0.0.1')
```